# Including svg file in sharelatex (overleaf)

Tags: texlive, overleaf, svg, inkscape, overleaf-toolkit

I was working with the online version of overleaf and the below code to include svg images worked perfectly fine.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[width = 5cm]{FIGURES/Example.svg}
    \caption{Example}
    \label{fig:Example}
\end{figure}
```

But now I switched to a local version of overleaf. I have installed the complete version of texlive as suggested [here](https://github.com/overleaf/toolkit/blob/master/doc/ce-upgrading-texlive.md). After the installation when I try to compile my latex file I had errors such as:

`` Package svg Error: File `Example_svg-tex.pdf' is missing. ``

and some warnings:

`` Package svg Warning: You didn't enable `shell escape' (or `write18') so it wasn't possible to launch the Inkscape export for `FIGURES/Example.svg' on input line 127. ``

I suppressed these errors and warnings by using a `latexmkrc` file containing `$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S';` as suggested elsewhere. But now I have new warnings:

`` Package svg Warning: No version of Inkscape was detected by invoking `inkscape -V' so the Inkscape export will fail quite sure as the command is probably unknown to your OS. You could set `inkscapeversion=<version>' manually but this is very unlikely to work on input line 8. ``

I am sure I have to set up the path of my Inkscape version somewhere, but I am just not sure where.

And I am working on ubuntu.

Comment: The roundabout can be converting it to an `eps` file which I usually do. There are also websites that are useful to do so like [cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-eps).

Comment: You must install [`inkscape`](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.1.1/) and try the command `inkscape -V` in a terminal...

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. The SVG inclusion relies on Inkscape as noted aboe. Unfortunately, `inkscape` is not installed on our compile servers, so it's not really possible to include SVGs directly.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry Note that EPS files have to be converted again to PDFs, so it's better to use PDFs directly.

Comment: @yo' You say ```inkscape``` is not installed on your compile servers. But I can compile my latex file while using the online version of overleaf. The problem appears when I try to compile overleaf in offline (locally) mode. So my guess is there must be a file, where overleaf looks for the inkscape path and where I can specify the inkscape path on my system. Or maybe I am wrong. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I have inkscape installed already @PaulGaborit and inkscape -V returns ```Inkscape 1.0.2 (1.0.2+r75+1)
    Pango version: 1.40.14
```

Comment: @UdayCK You must install `inkscape` into the Overleaf container...

Comment: @PaulGaborit If you don't mind, can you walk me through this process? Is it just installing Inkscape into the overleaf directory or is it more complicated than that? Do I have to use docker?

Comment: @UdayCK In your `overleaf` directory, you can try `./bin/shell` then, at the `root` prompt, `apt install inkscape`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thank you very much! This worked like a charm. Now I don't have to convert my svg to pdf!

Comment: @yo' Compiling `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\input|"inkscape -V"\end{document}` on Overleaf tells me that Inkscape 0.92.5 is installed.

Comment: @schtandard Ok right, sorry for having been wrong. For some reason was pretty sure that inkscape is not available in the SaaS Overleaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install `inkscape` in the `overleaf` container.

1. In your `overleaf` directory, run `./bin/shell` to connect to the container.
2. At the `root` prompt (`#`), run:

   - `apt update`
   - `apt install inkscape`.

Comment: Hi. I just tried this to fix the same problem but it did not fix the issue. I am using the standard [docker-compose](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/blob/main/docker-compose.yml).

Comment: Did you run `apt update` before `apt install inkscape`?

Comment: Yes I did, otherwise I wasn't able to even install the package as the APT caches weren't present. Can you try this with the docker-compose I mentioned in the previous comment, and see if it still works for you? I run the following command: `docker exec -it sharelatex bash -c 'apt update && apt install inkscape'`. Thanks!

Comment: @dodancs Here with `docker-compose` via `podman` it works.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Paul Gaborit's answer, I had to enable shell escape on my local installation, see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/overleaf/status/478279896020828160?lang=en)

In practice, I had to create a `latexmkrc` file with contents:

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape';
```

Once shell escape was enabled, it worked.